# SSL Error on Port 443, Page is not showing and resulting in error 404

Tags: ssl, https, cpanel

I just recently had to find a way to get a SSL certificate for my domain as facebook required this by the 1st of October as you may aware.

Therefore I signed and installed my startssl certificate on my server.

Now my problem is, when I try to go to one of my https sites it always asks me to make an exception for my certificate (which is okay at the moment) but after creating this exception my Server, which is as I know a linux server with an cPanel backend, fires a 404 page not found notification to me.

```
404 Not Found
The server can not find the requested page:

greentomatocars.com.au/fbtab/booking (port 443)
Please forward this error screen to greentomatocars.com.au's WebMaster.
```

[A FaceBook Tab HTTPS Site](https://greentomatocars.com.au/fbtab/booking)

Any diagnostics available what's this all about and whats the problem?

Any answer will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to configure your server to also serve your content on port 443 (https).  Right now it's still using the [cPanel default](https://greentomatocars.com.au/).

Comment: How can I change those settings so that my server will serve content on port 443?

Answer (score 3):

Once you installed ther certificates, you have to activate SSL via

```
Security -> SSL/TLS Manager -> Activate SSL on Your Web Site (HTTPS)
```

Comment: There was and is no such option! I can only add those certificates... how to enable port 443?

Answer (score 1):

If you got the 404, your SSL is working perfectly, as the "404" was transmitted via SSL. I would investigate the *actual* problem, which is the 404.

Answer (score 1):

i had similar problem on a server with few hosts (currentlly only one with https support)

i found the sulotion in [cpanel FAQ](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/SSL+FAQ+and+Troubleshooting#SSLFAQandTroubleshooting-Mycertificateinstalled,butvisitorswhotrytosecurelyaccessothersitesonthesharedIPaddresscanonlyseethesitewithaninstalledSSLcertificate,notmydefaultdomain.), i went to *WHM Home >> Service Configuration >> Apache Configuration >> Include Editor >> Pre Virtual Host Include*, and added the following lines:

```
<VirtualHost IPADDRESS:443>
    ServerName HOSTNAME
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache/htdocs
    ServerAdmin EMAIL
    <IfModule mod_suphp.c>
       suPHP_UserGroup MYUSER MYGROUP
    </IfModule>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile SSLCERTIFICATEFILE
    SSLCertificateKeyFile YOUR-SSLCERTIFICATEKEYFILE
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

I realize this question is 4 years old.

If you can access the html page at your root domain (say `https://midomain.com/`), but pages in a directory like `https://midomain.com/` give you a `404 Not Found` error, then you probably need to add these lines to your `httpd-ssl` file:

(applies to Apache 2.4)

```
 <Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All

    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
```