# Problems with SSL (port 443) and FB

Tags: facebook, https, port, cpanel

I 've got the same problem like in this question: [SSL Error on Port 443, Page is not showing and resulting in error 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908649/ssl-error-on-port-443-page-is-not-showing-and-resulting-in-error-404)

I'm trying to create a facebook application, but I have problems and I keep getting the same error as that person:

*Error 404
The server can not find the requested page:
--url-- (port 443)
Please forward this error screen to --url--'s WebMaster.*

I already created through the SSL/TLS Manager a Key, CSR and CRT for the domain that I'm using for the application, but I still cannot get to the index.php through https, while through http is all fine. There is no activate SSL button or anything like this, so I'm a bit lost -using cpanel for the first time-

Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is almost certainly a configuration problem with your web server not serving the right content on port 443, that error message is definitely from your web server's side and not from Facebook's API

Comment: @Izu. by configuring your server to serve your app over HTTPS as it already does for HTTP.